# Convert pixel values in thermal image with embedded metadata

Tags: python, arduino-esp32, leptonica, metadata-extractor, flir

I am capturing thermal images using a FLIR Lepton 3.5 thermal camera and ESP32 WROVER E module. I am getting the pixel values that I can see on the serial monitor. Then I convert these pixel values into thermal images using Python code. But when I am uploading this image in Flir tools software, I couldn't see the metadata of the image.
What should I do to get the image with it's proper metadata

I tried other libraries in Python and tried to save the image directly on the SD card. But nothing worked.

I am expecting that when I upload the image in Flir tools software, I should be able to see the metadata of the object.